# lidgren client cannot connect after disconnecting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lidgren

I'm using Lidgren to connect a unity game to a gameserver. everything works fine. the only problem is when the client disconnects from the server (by loss of internet connection or even manually) it cannot connect again. I have to close and reopen the game to be able to connect again. I have tried this outside the unity too and got the same results:

connection method is like this:

```
public IEnumerator Connect()
{
    m_Client.Start();
    var hail = m_Client.CreateMessage();
    AuthRequest id = new AuthRequest()
    {
        Name = PlayerSettings.Name,
    };

    hail.Write(new Packet(PacketType.AuthRequest, id).SerializePacket());
    m_Client.Connect(k_ServerAddress, k_Port, hail);
    Debug.Log("Connecting " + id.Name + " to " + k_ServerAddress + ":" + k_Port);

    NetConnectionStatus status = m_Client.ConnectionStatus;
    while (m_Client.ConnectionStatus != NetConnectionStatus.Disconnected)
    {
        if (m_Client.ConnectionStatus != status)
        {
            status = m_Client.ConnectionStatus;
            Debug.Log("Status: " + status);
        }
        yield return null;
    }

}
```

If I use this code:

```
LidgrenClient m_Client = new LidgrenClient();
m_Client.Connect();
```

the client gets connected, but when the client gets disconnected from the server the update method below just logs **Trying to Reconnect** every 5 minutes but actually does nothing:

```
void Update()
{
    if (!waiting && !m_Client.Connected)
    {
        Debug.Log("Trying to Reconnect");
        StartCoroutine(TryReconnect());
    }
    m_Client.ReadMessages();
}
IEnumerator TryReconnect()
{
    waiting = true;
    m_Client.Connect();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
    waiting = false;
}
```